# Manage a date roll where SQL Server Database is in NY time but reports are run based on AEST time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

A SQL extract needs to be run at 08:00 AEST (18:00 EST) to capture overnight trades and again at 17:00 AEST (03:00 EST) to captuure the trades for the current day.

I would like my criteria to update automatically as the date rolls in the NY db to the new trading day

I am running SQL Server 2012 so AT TIME ZONE function appears not to be available.

In my code below this works fine as I run it now at 13:48 AEST (22:48 EST) but when 18 Sep 00:00 EST comes around it will fail given the `getdate` will return the 18th and my minute offsets will be incorrect for the 17:00 AEST (03:00 EST) report.

Can I ask the best way to assign the current date/times and offsets to handle date rolls?

Get the system date and compare to the database date then update offsets using an if statement?

```
Declare @TODAY_DATE DateTime
select GETDATE() '@TODAY_DATE_TIME'
Set @TODAY_DATE = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0) -- Todays date with no time
select @TODAY_DATE '@TODAY_DATE'

-- Night session 
Declare @START_NIGHT_MINUTES Integer
Declare @END_NIGHT_MINUTES Integer
declare @START_NIGHT_DATE_TIME DateTime
declare @END_NIGHT_DATE_TIME DateTime
Set @START_NIGHT_MINUTES = 179 -- 03.09 NY / 17.09 AEST
Set @END_NIGHT_MINUTES = 1019 -- 17.00 NY / 07.00 AEST
set @START_NIGHT_DATE_TIME = DateAdd(n, @START_NIGHT_MINUTES, @TODAY_DATE)
select @START_NIGHT_DATE_TIME '@START_NIGHT_DATE_TIME'
set @END_NIGHT_DATE_TIME = DateAdd(n, @END_NIGHT_MINUTES, @TODAY_DATE)
select @END_NIGHT_DATE_TIME '@END_NIGHT_DATE_TIME'

-- Day Session
Declare @START_DAY_MINUTES Integer
Declare @END_DAY_MINUTES Integer
declare @START_DAY_DATE_TIME DateTime
declare @END_DAY_DATE_TIME DateTime
Set @START_DAY_MINUTES = 1020 -- 17.00 NY / 07.00 AEST
Set @END_DAY_MINUTES = 1620 -- 03.00 NY / 17.00 AEST
set @START_DAY_DATE_TIME = DateAdd(n, @START_DAY_MINUTES, @TODAY_DATE)
select @START_DAY_DATE_TIME '@START_DAY_DATE_TIME'
set @END_DAY_DATE_TIME = DateAdd(n, @END_DAY_MINUTES, @TODAY_DATE)
select @END_DAY_DATE_TIME '@END_DAY_DATE_TIME'
```

[image]